# How do I scan every element of an array except one index?

Tags: arrays, ruby, any, ruby-2.4

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  How do I scan every element of an array for a condition except one index in the array?  I tried this

```
arr.except(2).any? {|str| str.eql?("b")}
```

But got the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `except' for ["a", "b", "c"]:Array
```

but evidently what I read online about "except" is greatly exaggerated.

Comment: What exactly did you read about `except`, and where? Ruby arrays have no such method.  

Also, calling `.eql?` on strings is not terribly idiomatic; you can just do `str == "b"`.

Comment: I found a post where someone defines such a method themselves, but even there it is based on the value of the element, not its index.

Comment: [is this the one? :)](https://coderwall.com/p/skzsoa/ruby-array-except)

Comment: @MarkReed wouldn't `eql` be idiomatic to ruby considering most languages use some form of `==`? It also reads more like natural language.

Comment: `.eql?` is certainly Ruby, but using it to compare Strings is not typical in Ruby code - which is what I meant by "idiomatic Ruby".  *As long as both objects being compared are Strings*, `eql?` and `==` and `===` all perform the same comparison. And since far more languages use `==` for comparison than any of the others, it's usually considered the most natural choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
arr.reject.with_index { |_el, index| index == 2 }.any? { |str| str.eql?("b") }
```

Explanation:

```
arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr.reject.with_index { |_el, index| index == 2 }
#=> [0, 1, 3, 4, 5]
```

Shortening what you are doing:

```
arr.reject.with_index { |_el, index| index == 2 }.grep(/b/).any?
#=> true
```

Following the @Cary's comment, another option would be:

```
arr.each_with_index.any? { |str, i| i != 2 && str.eql?("b") }
```